# CiviCRM integration with Eventbrite

Tags: civievent, api, developer

I would like to create/update events in CiviEvent by using Eventbrite webhooks. One of the requirements is having an endpoint page that will receive data sent by Eventbrite API.

How can I create that endpoint page within CiviCRM?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to create extension to have Eventbrite sync with CiviEvents. Here is some guideline on how to approach this

1. [Create extension.](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-module)
2. Add [page](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-page) using civix
3. In run() use [CiviCRM api](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/) to create entries in civicrm table.

Reference :

Mandrill extension uses same approach i.e to create entries in various civicrm table upon webhook call. This might find you helpful to develop your extension
https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.mte/blob/master/CRM/Mte/Page/callback.php

Comment: Did this ever proceed to production? It would be great to know if so, as EventBrite becomes an increasingly popular forum for event publicity...

Answer (score 4):

There is now an [extension for EventBrite integration](https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.eventbrite).